# NG8001: 'app-welcome' is not a known element:

Tags: angular

I've encountered an issue with my Angular application, and I'm getting error 8001. I'm not sure how to handle it. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

app.component.html

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<p>Congratulations! Your app is running. </p>
<app-welcome></app-welcome>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'XYZCARS';
}
```

welcome.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome',
  templateUrl: './welcome.component.html',
  styleUrl: './welcome.component.css'
})
export class WelcomeComponent {
  car = 'toyota';
}
```

My project initially did not have an `app.module.ts` file. I added it myself and configured it based on some information I found online, but the issue persists and remains unresolved. Can anyone help me with this?

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: remove the `app.module` file, since you have `standalone: true` add that same to your `WelcomeComponent` then modify the `imports` array in your `AppComponent` and add to the array the `WelcomeComponent` (same you did in the module)

Comment: I followed your instructions, but I'm unsure if my approach is correct. Unfortunately, I haven't been successful.

Comment: If you're seeing the error “NG8001” in your Angular project, it's likely that you're using a newer version of the Angular CLI than is supported by the version of Angular you're using. To fix this, you can either downgrade the Angular CLI to an older version or upgrade Angular to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating project in angular 17->use these command ng app --no-standalone
then you get app.module.ts file intially.

Answer (score 0):

A component can be "standalone" or declare in a NgModule.

If the main component is "standalone", the main.ts bootstrap it using

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [...]
})
```

If the main component is not "standalone" the main.ts boostrap the Module using some like

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

When a "standalone" component use another component, if the component is standalone should be add to the "imports" array

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true, //<--see is standalone
  imports:[AnotherComponent,....], //<--import directly the "AnotherComponent"
  template: ``
})
export class AppComponent{...}
```

If the another component is not standalone, the standaloneComponent should import the module where is declared the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true, //<--see is standalone
  imports:[AnotherModule,....], //<--import the "Module"
  template: ``
})
export class AppComponent{...}
```

Where AnotherModule should export the component

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AnotherComponent  //<--declare the "AnotherComponent"
  ],
  imports:[...]
  exports:[AnotherComponent], //<--AND should be declare as "exportable"
  providers: [...],
})
export class AnotherModule { }
```

So, **choose**

1. if you want your main component is standalone or not
2. if you want your "wellcome" component is a standalone or not

**EXTRA** If your main component is a standalone component and use Router you need indicate when boostrap the aplication, see the [provideRouter](https://angular.io/api/router/provideRouter) in the code and check the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#routing-and-lazy-loading)

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES),
    ...
  ]
}
```