# Angular standalone componentnot getting imported properly and after getting imported properly, not displaying anything on html

Tags: angular, typescript

So I am pretty new to Angular and, currently I am making a clone by using Firebase and all. So, Angular is throwing two error's to me named:

1. Component AppComponent is standalone, and cannot be declared in an NgModule. Did you mean to import it instead?
2. The `AppComponent` class is a standalone component, which can not be used in the `@NgModule.bootstrap` array. Use the `bootstrapApplication` function for bootstrap instead.

This is the app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponentComponent } from './login-component/login-component.component';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from "@angular/material/form-field";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp({
      apiKey: "YOUR API KEY",
      authDomain: "YOUR AUTH DOMAIN",
      databaseURL: "YOUR DATABASE URL",
      projectId: "YOUR PROJECT ID",
      storageBucket: "YOUR STORAGE BUCKET",
      messagingSenderId: "YOUR SENDER ID",
      appId: "YOUR APP ID",
      measurementId: "YOUR MEASUREMENT ID"
    })),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
}
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the app.compnent.module.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterLinkActive, RouterOutlet, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet,
    RouterLink, RouterLinkActive],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'zomato-clone';
}
```

I can't figure out what to do. Can Someone please help? Thank you in advance.

I tried removing the AppComponent from declarations and bootstrap, it did compile but I was not able to see anything on the HTML. I was expecting to see the navbar that I had designed in the html doc, but just saw just a blank page.

Comment: check, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77511540/ng8001-app-welcome-is-not-a-known-element/77784961#77784961) to see the diference between bootstrap a module and bootstrap a standalone component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `standalone: true` and `imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive],` from `app.component`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'zomato-clone';
}
```

In app.module ts :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponentComponent } from './login-component/login-component.component';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from "@angular/material/form-field";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterLinkActive, RouterOutlet, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule, // add here if necessasry
    RouterLinkActive,// add here if necessasry
    RouterOutlet, // add here if necessasry
    RouterLink,// add here if necessasry
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp({
      apiKey: "YOUR API KEY",
      authDomain: "YOUR AUTH DOMAIN",
      databaseURL: "YOUR DATABASE URL",
      projectId: "YOUR PROJECT ID",
      storageBucket: "YOUR STORAGE BUCKET",
      messagingSenderId: "YOUR SENDER ID",
      appId: "YOUR APP ID",
      measurementId: "YOUR MEASUREMENT ID"
    })),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
}
export class AppModule { }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'zomato-clone';
    }
```