# Angular TicTacToe project

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, nomachine-nx

I am currently working on a tictactoe game and I am unable to resolve an error in my program.

```
 ✘ [ERROR] TS2305: Module '"./app/app.component"' has no exported member 'AppComponent'. [plugin angular-compiler]
    src/main.server.ts:2:9:
      2 │ import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
        ╵          ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ✘ [ERROR] TS2305: Module '"./app/app.component"' has no exported member 'AppComponent'. [plugin angular-compiler]
    src/main.ts:3:9:
      3 │ import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
        ╵          ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ✘ [ERROR] No matching export in "src/app/app.component.ts" for import "AppComponent"
    src/main.server.ts:2:9:
      2 │ import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

app.component.ts
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-square',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class SquareComponent {
  title = 'TicTacToeApp';
}
```

Currently running angular 17.0.4

I have tried to edit the selector name....from "app-root" to "app-square"

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title of the question summarizes the issue. Currently, we can only tell the question is about a tic-tac-toe game built with Angular.

Comment: Should be `SquareComponent`, not `AppComponent`. BTW, if you use as "main component" with different name and selector that the "clasic" names, check this two SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77511540/ng8001-app-welcome-is-not-a-known-element/77784961#77784961 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245404/structure-of-an-angular-project-file-index-html/75245866#75245866

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are using NX, we need to create components using `nx console` we need to generate a standalone component named square, then we need to import square component to app component in the imports array
2. after importing we can add square component to the root component by giving `<app-square></app-square>` inside the `app.component.html` so that you can start coding the tic tac toe application inside the square component.
3. After this I ran npm run start and the application worked fine!

app ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { SquareComponent } from './square/square.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, SquareComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'TicTacToeApp';
}
```

app html

```
<app-square></app-square> <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

square ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-square',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './square.component.html',
  styleUrl: './square.component.css'
})
export class SquareComponent { }
```

square html

```
<p>square works!</p>
```

Comment: If I update all instances of AppComponent to SquareComponent , I receive a "maximum call stack size exceeded," error.