# I have an Angular Problem with Modules and components

Tags: angular, module, components, stackblitz

I'm learning Angular databinding concept and started trying out using StackBlitz.

This is my [my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID8xp.png)

Here is my,

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { BindingModule } from './binding/binding.module';

bootstrapApplication(BindingModule);
```

**binding.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BindingComponent } from './binding.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, BrowserModule],
  declarations: [BindingComponent],
  bootstrap: [BindingComponent],
})
export class BindingModule {}
```

**binding.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-binding',
  templateUrl: './binding.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./binding.component.css']
})
export class BindingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And I have an HTML `<p>` to be printed which is ***binding works!***

But I end up with the the following error:

> Error: NG0906: The BindingModule is not an Angular component, make sure it has the `@Component` decorator.

Please help!

Comment: You need understand the **two** different ways to bootstrap an Angular aplication: using standalone components **or** using modules, see the two ways in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77511540/ng8001-app-welcome-is-not-a-known-element/77784961#77784961).  this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245404/structure-of-an-angular-project-file-index-html/75245866#75245866) can also be a bit help

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the old way (modules) and new way (standalone components), in standalone components there is no need to declare a module, we can remove the binding module and declare binding component with standalone and add the imports there like so.

[Standalone docs](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components)

binding.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-binding',
  imports: [CommonModule], // <- browser module is not needed!
  templateUrl: './binding.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./binding.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
})
export class BindingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Then finally we can intialize the component like so

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { BindingComponent } from './binding.component';

bootstrapApplication(BindingComponent);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vwtc3e?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Thank you Naren this worked. But I have a question probably because I'm newly learning Angular. How do we know which way to use to  bootstrap an Angular application

Comment: @Lakshmi Its your preference only, we can achieve both using both `modules` and `standalone`, since angular goes for `standalone` by default, I recommend standalone, but lazy loaded modules were very popular before standalone was implemented!